# Is there an easy way to do referrer based advertising?

Tags: advertising, startup

This a bit of a weird question so please let me know if you need more information.
For a side project I am working on I need to ability to generate advertising on a specific page based on a specified domain. I have looked a bit and haven't found anything that really fits this so I'm hoping someone here has a service like this or can push me in the correct direction. I'm not super interested in finding my own advertiser/rolling my own solution currently (not to say it wont happen in the future), looking for more of an out of the box solution.
Clarification: The advertising on this page will be generated based upon the referral URL. So in other words instead of the advertising content being contextual to the page it is delivered on.. it is contextual to a domain/URL.
TYIA

Comment: Do you mean, you want to have different advertisers for different referrers? Like AdSense for people coming from site X and AdBrite for users coming from site Y?

Answer (score 1):

adsense and doubleclick already have something similar.  Lets say you go to shopify.com, chances are you will see shopify ads served by google on sites you visit.  They do it based on cookies.

You can do a request referrer and show ads based on who the referrer is yourself.